# PySpark - Write data frame into Hive table

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, hive, parquet

I have an empty Hive table. I have 18 jobs that I am running, and each one could have a data frame that I would need to add into the Hive table with a parquet file.

What I have is something like this:

```
df2.write.parquet(SOME_HDFS_DIR/my_table_dir)
```

But this doesn't seem quite right. Do I have to add some `.parquet` file name and keep appending it each time? I have seen some syntax is Scala but not Python.

Answer (score 0):

`df.write.parquet` will overwrite the parquet files of the location, but with the option,

```
df.write.mode('append').parquet('path')
```

then it will create a new parquet file to the path and so you can read the data from the table.

Comment: The table is already created. I just want to insert data (the dataframe) into it.

Comment: Is there no way to just do it like `df2.write.format("parquet)".insertInto(___)?